# VsCode can't resolve Django Imports

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pipenv, python-venv

I just woke up and shockingly VsCode can't resolve imports in all my Django projects.
Some were using `venv` and some `pipenv`, but they have all stopped resolving imports.
I have tried the answers which all seem to say I should select the `python.exe` from the `Script` folder of the respective project`s` virtual environment`. But as you can see below, that ain't working.

[image]

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the clear cache and reload option in the command palette?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P into vscode to open the command palette and type "Python: Clear Cache..".

Comment: It didn't work.